# ICredentials in HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, credentials

I've tried to make a web request and noticed that it requires credentials based on `ICredentials` interface.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(UrlID);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
request.ContentType = "text/json";
request.Credentials = this.Credentials;
```

I've implemented that interface in my configuration class, so I could skip passing user name and password between classes.

```
public NetworkCredential GetCredential(Uri uri, string authType)
{
    return new NetworkCredential(Login, _Password);
}
```

However, it fails to authenticate. I've found another way to do it with `CredentialCache` that works (note that the same `NetworkCredential` is passed):

```
CredentialCache cc = new CredentialCache();
cc.Add(
    UrlID,
    "Basic",
    this.Credentials.GetCredential(UrlID, "Basic"));
request.Credentials = cc;
```

Question is why they behave differently even if they both inherit from `ICredentials`? Shouldn't `HttpWebRequest` have access only to `GetCredential` method, which should return same `NetworkCredential` object?

Thank you for any clarification.

Comment: I could not test it myself yet, but what I recognised is that in your GetCredential function you are passing two parameters which you do not use anywhere. Sure you do not have to pass them further to the constructor?

Comment: @rekcul `NetworkCredential` does not have property `Uri`, nor constructor that takes `Uri` as parameter.